# "/" URLs without trailing slash shows 404

Tags: rewrite-rules

By default any URL on my website will end with a trailing slash.

So if I publish a post or page, the URL will end with a "/".

But I came across a weird situation where I hit publish but the URL with "/" works but without "/" does not work. And when I clear the cache on the WordPress website. both URLS work. with or without trailing slash. And the browser will automatically redirect/change the URL to end with a slash, even if I forgot to put "/" at the end of the URL.

I was reading this article to see properly configure my rewrite rules. https://www.danielmorell.com/guides/htaccess-seo/redirects/https-www-and-trailing-slash

If anyone can help me understand what this issue could be.

It looks like cache issue, but could it be a rewrite rules issue?

**Hosted on AWS Lightsail, Bitnami WordPress stack.**

Comment: You’ve tagged this with wordpress.com-hosting. Is your site hosted with them?

Comment: @JacobPeattie my bad. Its hosted on AWS Lightsail, Bitnami WordPress stack.